# Arrow function in angular html

Tags: angular, components, arrow-functions

I wonder if it's possible to use an arrow function in a component like this in Angular

```
<app-child [showItemCondition]="item => item.isVisible" [list]="items"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any functions cannot be defined in templates. To make it possible, then we need to eval  those code in JIT compilation mode.

Prohibition to use arrow function allows to get rid of unnecessary code (DRY and KISS) and as a result:

- it's easier to read
- you don't have to go to keep going back to the component to see what each function is really doing.
- using component templates with functions that primarily belongs to classes would result in poor quality code that is hard to maintain.

If you need a function, it should be defined as component class method. It can be either regular or arrow function.

If logic will be placed in template, it means:

- that logic will be placed in different places. You have to go back and forth between template and class.
- it will harder to maintain to other programmers because they did not expect to have logic in UI. So logic is spread in different places. In my view, it breaks all principles such as SRP. And it makes really hard to maintain code to other future developers
- even this just one line of code makes code harder to debug

Comment: Can you please tell me more about "eval those code in JIT compilation mode."? Any links? Is it just to use eval(...)?

Comment: @YugoHarago [you can read more about evaluation here in official docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Comment: Original, is a good example of utility of this feature. Usually advised workaround to define support function in component makes code less readable. In my opinion, not allowing simple arrow functions in templates harms more than helps.

Comment: I do not agree that it is better to avoid arrow functions, quite opposite, I think simple arrow functions would made templates and code simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @VladimirNesterovsky but your logic will be placed in different places. You have to go back and forth between template and class. It will harder to maintain to other programmers because they did not expect to have logic in UI. So logic is spread in different places. In my view, it breaks all principles such as SRP. And it makes really hard to maintain code to other future developers.

Comment: Original example specifically deals with UI logic and not with business logic. In my opinion, developer would benefit from such logic to be part of template. This is exactly the same argument as with simple expressions as part of template.

Comment: @VladimirNesterovsky i think the question is wider than example of code and looks like this - `if it's possible to use an arrow function in a component.` Even this just one line of code makes code harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

As Guerric say, is not possible, you should defined, e.g.

```
  condition=(item)=>item.isVisible
  //or
  condition=(item)=>{
    return item.isVisible
  }
  condition(item){
    return item.isVisible
  }
```

And pass the function as arg

```
<app-child [showItemCondition]="condition" [list]="items"></app-child>
```

In your child

```
@Input()showItemCondition:any

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{showItemCondition(item)}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in order to customize the behavior of the `ChildComponent`, as long as the callback doesn't have a reference on the parent. In that case, you should refactor your code with an `@Output()`.

However, you can't declare a function inside the template so you have to assign it in a variable of the parent and pass that variable to the child. The function should also be declared as a classic function (not arrow), otherwise, `this` will refer to the parent.